# John The Ripper and OpenCL on AMD FirePro

Tags: hash, password-cracking

Trying to work with John 1.8.0 Jumbo 1 I noticed that OpenCL won't work for me. I used autoconfig (meaning configure and build with the option to enable OpenMPI) in order to build JTR for my Mac Pro. In order to have a chance to crack a specific agilekeychain hash I used (folder is the run folder):

`./john --test --format=agilekeychain-opencl`

Unfortunately, this comes back:

`Device 1: AMD Radeon HD - FirePro D300 Compute Engine
Local worksize (LWS) 64, global worksize (GWS) 524288
Benchmarking: agilekeychain-opencl, 1Password Agile Keychain [PBKDF2-SHA1 OpenCL AES]... FAILED (cmp_all(1))`

I found a possible idea for a [solution](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2013/03/17/2) but I can't get it to work. None of the OpenCL Algorithms works for me. Using it without OpenCL works just fine.

Comment: Is the error shown when trying to run [hashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/)? Tips on installing the drivers can be found [here](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=oclhashcat_catalyst_forceware).